# I want to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty cos(n^2\pi)\cdot(\sqrt{n+11}-\sqrt{n+2}) $ converges or diverges.

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty cos(n^2\pi)\cdot(\sqrt{n+11}-\sqrt{n+2}) $ is convergent (or divergent).

I am lost on how to prove it. Could someone please show me? I assume I would need to use one of the criterias for determining convergence?

I know that $cos(n^2\pi)$ is basicly the same as $(-1)^n$.

I tried to multiplicate it by $ \frac {\sqrt{n+11}+\sqrt{n+2}}{\sqrt{n+11}+\sqrt{n+2}} $ to see if I could get something more useful, which got me: $a_n=(-1)^n(\sqrt{n+11}-\sqrt{2+n})=\frac{9(-1)^n}{\sqrt{11+n}+\sqrt{2+n}}$.

Here I guess I would want to see both cases - odd $n$ and even $n$.

For the even case - the limit would be $\frac{9}{\sqrt{\frac{11}{n}+1}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}+1}}=\frac{9}{2}$ and odd case would result in $-\frac{9}{2}$.

Is this enough? Is it even correct? So it is divergent, because there are 2 limits?

Comment: You're confusing the *sequence* $(a_n)$ and the *series* $\sum a_n$, and there is miscalculation.

Comment: See leibniz theorem on alternate séries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Leibnz's rule: showing that $$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{9}{\sqrt{11+n}+\sqrt{2+n}}=0
$$ and $$\frac{9}{\sqrt{12+n}+\sqrt{3+n}}<
\frac{9}{\sqrt{11+n}+\sqrt{2+n}}
$$ and this is obviuos. Therefore the series converges

Comment: if I get it right, it is basicly this: $\frac{9}{\sqrt{11+(n+1)}+\sqrt{2+(n+1)}}<
\frac{9}{\sqrt{11+n}+\sqrt{2+n}}$ ? Don't I have to prove it? And how diid you get that the limit is 0?

Answer (score 1):

You may just use the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) to :
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{9(-1)^n}{\sqrt{11+n}+\sqrt{2+n}}
$$
since
$$
\frac{9}{\sqrt{11+n}+\sqrt{2+n}} 
$$ is a decreasing sequence tending to $0$.

Comment: So I want to prove that the series is decreasing and that its limit is 0? Could you please show me how?

Comment: @Mykybo You know that $x \mapsto \sqrt{11+x}+\sqrt{2+x}$ is increasing over $[1,\infty)$ (see the derivative if necessary) with limit equals to $\infty$, thus its reciprocal is decreasing to $0$.